# Why did Amazon workers at the Bessemer, Alabama warehouse vote against forming a union?

Tags: united-states, labor-union

Recently Amazon workers at a warehouse in Bessemer, Alabama voted [down](https://www.theverge.com/2021/4/9/22374540/amazon-union-vote-outcome-bessemer-alabama-rwdsu-bhm1) the union campaign. What I understand is unionization helps general workers. It generally means that the workers can bargain collectively which translates into higher wages and benefits, better working conditions, fewer layoffs, etc. That is why I find it very strange that workers are rejecting unionization.

What are some arguments from the workers' side against unionization? It is better if you can provide Alabama specific example.

Comment: Amazon might have the economical power of a small country, but it is still a private company. So this is not a question about politics and political processes. But perhaps https://workplace.stackexchange.com can provide you more information about what unions do in a workplace and why employees might decide against them.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Two issues mentioned in [this npr report](https://www.npr.org/2021/04/09/982139494/its-a-no-amazon-warehouse-workers-vote-against-unionizing-in-historic-election?t=1617988945154):

- The workers might think that union dues cut into their wages.
- The workers might think that they can negotiate a better deal for themselves without an union.

Note that these were raised by Amazon itself. How genuine employees are when they repeat them is hard to tell.

Additionally, from the end of [this cnbc report](https://www.cnbc.com/2019/08/22/how-amazon-is-fighting-back-against-workers-efforts-to-unionize.html):

- The workers might think that unionization makes the company more unwieldly and thus ultimately cut into their own career prospects.

The second bullet point above seems to be quite common in highly paid, highly sought-after professions. When the threat of the employee resigning is an actual *threat* to the employer, unions appear less necessary.

Finally, and I *don't* know if that was raised in the Alabama case, workers might fear that unionizing will cause the employer to shut a site down, fire all employees, and open a new site where there are no unions. One might call that blackmail, and it doesn't have to be spelled out in detail to change opinions. [This BBC report](https://www.bbc.com/news/business-55927024) mentions fear by city officials that the city would get less attractive to businesses, which is a similar statement.